# DDD Repository: Use DAO for separation?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, dao

There is a controversial discussion of [Repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), their use and layout on stackoverflow and throughout the web. I am confused about how to implement the data access abstraction (e.g. database) behind a Repository efficiently.

I am not using an ORM tool/framework as I want to see the gritty details myself. At the moment I am using DAO objects to access a (mysql) database and provide Business Objects (domain objects). Associations given by foreign keys in the database tables are resolved and loaded within the DAO of the respective object (no lazy loading currently). As I don't want to use my database DAOs directly in the business logic I considered a Repository to be a good further abstraction. I got stuck when implementing sophisticated queries like *GetEmployeesByShopAndPosition()* in the Repository: I see two possibilities to implement this:

1. Brute Force: Use the Employee DAO and load *all* employees as business objects (including associated shops/positions) from the database into the Repository's collection. Iterate through collection and return those Employees working in the given Shop and Position.
2. Efficient: Implement a database query that joins the concerned tables and returns only wanted Employees by where clause in the EmployeeDAO.

The first approach uses the collection nature a Repository should actually have, but seems to be very inefficient. The second approach generates a [bloated DAO](http://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/) but is much more efficient.

My questions:

1. What is to prefer here or how is it done in practice?
2. Am I wrong and the Repository should not be used in conjunction with DAOs and the database related code can go directly in the Repository?
3. As a Repository deals with *aggregates*, should it actually assemble the associated foreign keys to build (full) Business Objects instead of the DAOs I am currently using?

I know this topic is not black/white as the involved design patterns can also be implemented in different ways, but I guess there are some guidelines that should not be broken or confused to get seperation of concerns and Persistence Ignorance (PI).

Comment: While I understand the desire to avoid using an ORM tool/framework, I do think you are making things much harder on yourself by not looking at their documentation and examples.  PHP's Doctrine 2 ORM (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product) is easy to understand and should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually asking quite a number of questions here so I'll try to keep the answers as terse as possible :)

Repositories return an `Aggregate Root` or an `Entity`.  Some are quite adamant that repositories only return ARs and that is fine and will always suffice.

There are two types of repositories (as nicely descibed by Vaughn Vernon in his *Implementing Domain-Driven Design* book):

- collection-oriented
- persistence-oriented

You'll probably come across and use the persistence-oriented more often.  This is probably where the confusion comes in w.r.t. DAO.  A DAO may, of course, return a business object but it is probably going to return more than that.

Your *query* example is where a DAO may be more appropriate.  So in the domain-driven design field you'll come across CQRS (command/query responsibility segregation) quite often.  It boils down to *not* querying your domain.

You should have a thin, dedicated, *query* layer that returns results in the most appropriate format (but not entities).  In c# I use things like `DataTable`, `DataRow`, `string` and sometimes a complex DTO if required.

A repository is only concerned with ARs, e.g.:

- Get
- Add
- Remove

Repositories basically use a logical DAO of sorts (ADO.NET, ORM --- I try to avoid ORMs).

The second bit about retrieving an AR with the associated foreign keys: an AR should *never* contain a reference to another AR.  Entities and `Value Objects` are fine.  For associated ARs either use an ID or a Value Object to represent the foreign AR.  The AR may consist of a complex structure itself but do not confuse ownership with containment.  An `OrderLine` is contained in an `Order`.  A `Customer` owns an `Order`.  So `Order` will have a `OrderLine` collection but not a reference to a `Customer` object (rather ID/VO).

The `Order`/`OrderLine` example illustrates why we wouldn't query the domain.  When we want a list of orders between a given start and end date we are probably not interested in all the order data and certainly not in the order lines.  So no sense in loading these aggregates.  This is where, when querying the domain, nasty things like lazy-loading creep in.  Lazy-loading should not exist IMHO :) --- a simple query layer would suffice here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Lots of interesting points here, thx. Are entities and business objects used here synonymously? I try to create a rich domain model and want to work with *proper* objects rather than performant queried raw data, but I think that is inefficient and not the goal. I tried constructing Business Objects in Repositories with all references(foreign keys) resolved and loaded. Not querying the domain seems a good approach to me.

Comment: Entities and business objects / domain objects are indeed synonymous.  Trying to construct an AR with all associated references will always cause pain --- a good indication that something may be amiss.

Comment: @EbenRoux great answer. In your opinion where will this query layer live? Will you access it via the application layer using the boundary dto's or have it completely separate from the ddd app structure?

Comment: @SneakyPeet: thanks :) --- logically, just as repository interfaces live in the domain and then one would have infrastructure implementation(s), the query 'layer' is probably something separate with its own infrastructure implementation(s).  Physically, however, I tend to place all of them (repositories / querying) in one assembly (e.g. Company.BoundedContext.dll).  If I *really* need to split this out then I do.  You just have to be cognizant of the logical separation when creating them in the same assembly to facilitate splitting if required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the power of the database whenever you can. That's what an ORM would try to do -- get as much filtering, sorting, etc. as possible inside the SQL query.
2. I see little value in having both Repositories and DAO's. They both abstract out the persistent storage. If you want to go without an ORM, you'll typically handle the database query generation part in the concrete Repository implementation. But in a collaborative application, this also leaves other complex things to implement, such as change tracking, transaction management, etc.
3. Full in the sense of one whole Aggregate, yes. But as a modelling good practice, try not to store (and thus rehydrate) references to other Aggregate Roots in an Aggregate.

That's from a "classical" DDD perspective, but if you want to go the CQRS route (some will say it's the only sensible one ;), definitely follow @EbenRoux's advice.

Comment: I had the approach to use database power for querying in conjunction with lots of scripts delivering the data to the client, what works fast, but I had no structure and seperation of concerns. So I created a DAO fetching data from database for every entity, but I got stuck when doing joined queries in a specific DAO. Where to put the data from tables being joined? Create entities directly using the *foreign* DAOs? Constructing Business objects from queried data to use the domain model, but being significantly slower? I think I am to much addicted to Business Objects :)

Comment: DDD's Repositories aren't a 1-to-1 map to business objects (entities), they rehydrate whole Aggregates, i.e. clusters with multiple entities in them. This is IMO the main difference between DAO's and Repositories. Maybe you should look into the concept of Aggregate more and it will all make sense.

Comment: Yes, I have ordered the DDD book by Vaughn Vernon to dig deeper in the concepts of repositories/aggregates.